# Plotly.express, pandas and NaNs

Tags: pandas, plotly, pie-chart

Based on the code below, I want to visualise my data in plotly. However, the pie chart I created shows also Nulls, which I want to omit.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['January', 'Violin'],
        ['February', 'Piano'], 
        ['March', 'Violin'],
        ['February', 'Violin'],
        ['January', 'Piano'],
        ['January', 'Violin']], 
    columns=['Month', 'Instrument']
)

df = df.pivot(columns='Month', values='Instrument')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("Select a month:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my_dropdown',
        value = 'January',
        options=[
                  {'label': 'January', 'value': 'January'},
                  {'label': 'February', 'value': 'February'},
                  {'label': 'March', 'value': 'March'}
        ],
        clearable=False,
        style={"width": "50%"}
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="pie-chart"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("pie-chart", "figure"),
    [Input("my_dropdown", "value")])
def generate_chart(my_dropdown):
    fig = px.pie(df, names=my_dropdown)
    return fig

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In this case, should I change something into the plotly part of the code or should I convert my initial DataFrame differently (instead of using the df.pivot() option)?

[image: null should not be visible]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is a count of the number of instances of each instrument, so I don't think you need to pivot your DataFrame. You can leave it as is:

```
df
      Month Instrument
0   January     Violin
1  February      Piano
2     March     Violin
3  February     Violin
4   January      Piano
5   January     Violin
```

If you pass the argument `names='Instrument'` to `px.pie`, it will create the pie chart by counting occurrences of the unique values in the `Instrument` column, and you won't have to worry about null values appearing. Then you can subset your DataFrame by the month that the user selects in dash in your `generate_chart` function.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['January', 'Violin'],
        ['February', 'Piano'], 
        ['March', 'Violin'],
        ['February', 'Violin'],
        ['January', 'Piano'],
        ['January', 'Violin']], 
    columns=['Month', 'Instrument']
)

# df = df.pivot(columns='Month', values='Instrument')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("Select a month:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my_dropdown',
        value = 'January',
        options=[
                  {'label': 'January', 'value': 'January'},
                  {'label': 'February', 'value': 'February'},
                  {'label': 'March', 'value': 'March'}
        ],
        clearable=False,
        style={"width": "50%"}
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="pie-chart"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("pie-chart", "figure"),
    [Input("my_dropdown", "value")])
def generate_chart(my_dropdown):
    fig = px.pie(
        df[df['Month'] == my_dropdown], 
        names='Instrument'
    )
    # fig = px.pie(df, names=my_dropdown)
    return fig

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]